# How to implement a global pressed button counter

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to implement a counter that shows how many times a button is pressed. I can do this for a local user using cookies, but I would like to make it a counter of all users who have ever pressed the button, I am just not sure of the best way to go about this.

```
var counter = getCookie("buttonCount") || 0;

counter++;

document.cookie = 'buttonCount=' + counter + ";max-age" + (90) + ";";

document.getElementById("pressedCount").innerHTML = "Button pressed " + counter + " times";
```

Would it be possible to read in an integer from a file in the same directory as the html file, increment the value and write it back to the file?

Comment: You'll need some server-side logic going into this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a simple server side script - using PHP or any other language that suits - that will store any user click and save it to file or database. Then on page load use another script to extract information about click count and display it for the user.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be accomplished on just the client-side. What server-side language, if any, are you using?